Bitbucket build fails, but local build succeeds with .EditorConfig errors
I'm building some C# (.net6 core) code with a fairly complex .editorconfig file.
All csproj files have
<EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>true</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
There is only 1 .editorconfig, and it is in the root folder, with
root = true
The code builds without errors (without even any intellisense errors) in Visual Studio 2022 (latest version), and also on the command line with
dotnet build --configuration Debug MySolution.sln
When I build on the BitBucket pipeline (with exactly the same dotnet build), I get lots of
error IDE0040: Accesibility modifiers required

The errors are correct, but I don't get the error building locally.
How do I get my local builds to match the more stringent BB builds?
EDIT
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <AccelerateBuildsInVisualStudio>true</AccelerateBuildsInVisualStudio>
        <DocumentationFile>bin\$(Configuration)\($AssemblyName).xml</DocumentationFile>
        <EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>true</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    </PropertyGroup>

## Removed <ItemGroup> PacketReferences / ProjectReferences

</Project>

There are no conditional parts of the csproj.
SOLUTION?
I've got a bit further, but it's not ideal.  There are TWO different ways to configure some items as errors.  CodeStyle and Analyzers potentially control the same thing.
Code Style -> Modifier preference -> Require accessibility modifiers
Analyzers -> IDE0040

So BB builds your solution with dotnet build --configuration Debug MySolution.sln too? Are you sure?

@GoodNightNerdPride I can copy directly from the build script on the server logs (or the build script itself) to a local command prompt, and it doesn't fail.

Could you show us your one of the .csproj files where BB finds errors? How did you configure dotnet_style_require_accessibility_modifiers (IDE0040) in your .editorconfig? What happens when you try --configuration Release locally?

I've added the csproj to the question.  Interestingly, rebuilding with Release DOES generate errors, but there are no conditional items in the csproj.

I found the problem.
It was to do with the file line endings.
.gitattribute has the setting text=auto, which means that the line endings should match the OS (LF for Linux, CRLF for Windows).
Editorconfig had a line

end_of_line = CRLF

Locally, the code was correct (git checkout on windows give CRLF line endings), but on the server it was wrong (git checkout on Lines gives LF line endings, which then caused a build error because it wanted CRLF).
The answer (long discussion here: https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/issues/226 ) is to use

end_of_line = unset

Which ignores the line endings.
Weirdly, this only broke the build on 2 lines in one source file, despite 1000s of other files that had the wrong line endings.
